# How to limit number of bundles generated in webpack 4 for entry?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Can someone please explain how to configure `splitChunks` plugin in webpack 4, so it generates only one bundle for app (index) and one bundle (or multiple) for node modules. Currently I have the following config -

```
entry: {
    app: ['./path-to-file.js']
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.[hash].js',
    <etc>
}
```

and in optimization section -

```
optimization: { 
    splitChunks: false, // It is set to false just for testing
}
```

Even if `splitChunks` plugin is set to `false`, instead of having one app bundle, I get this -

```
 [0].bundle.XXX.js
 [1].bundle.XXX.js
 ...
 [11].bundle.XXX.js
```

And I do not know how to limit the number of bundles generated.

I tried to use `LimitChunkCountPlugin` plugin as suggested here [reference](https://medium.com/@glennreyes/how-to-disable-code-splitting-in-webpack-1c0b1754a3c5) and set `maxChunks` to `1` - this worked and I got only one app bundle, but the issue now is, I cannot use `splitChunks` plugin to split node modules because when I enlarge `maxChunks` value for `LimitChunkCountPlugin` plugin, it starts splitting app first and results in multiple [0]-[11] app bundles again. Can you please explain why this happens?

I am using webpack 4.